# Installing Microsoft Windows VM on OS X

Tags: macos, startup, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm kinda new to the Mac OS, in fact I got this current Mac this week so I'm pretty noob with it.

I need to run a VM with windows 11 and 10 for testing purposes. So I downloaded  and the virtual machines from MS in this link 
[VM Dev](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/)

After doing all the proper steps to install it, anytime I run one of the machines it get a blue screen on booting, and the VM restart itself.

**Here is the error**

[image]

Working on a MacBook pro 15" with latest OS el capitan (but tested before on yosemite and the same thing happened)

This is the Machine configuration

[image]

Comment: Can you use Windows with Boot Camp? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_(software)?wprov=sfti1

Comment: No, i cannot, rather use a VM, mostly in order not to use 2 laptops just for testing in IE crap

Comment: Is the Windows image you have downloaded a 32-bit or 64-bit ?? - I can see you VM setup is running in 32-bit.

Comment: @ReneLarsen when you download them it doesn't specifiy the architecture, I tried both, 64 and 32 bits, that capture is from the 32 test, but it's happening on both

Comment: Okay - next question :) - have you tried the image designed for Virtual Box ?? - a .vmdk image is a VMware image.

Comment: @ReneLarsen yes, i've downloaded the one's for VBox, after the .zip decompress I get a .vmdk file as you said, but if it's so its an error from MS itself, (check the download link on my question)

Comment: also read here [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMDK) .vmdk also it's used in VirtualBox

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that you wish to transfer an existing Windows machine configuration, with all its apps and data, to your Mac? If so, and Boot Camp is a no-no, then you need something like Parallels Desktop 11, which will enable you to run Windows 7, 8 or 10 alongside OS X and switch from one to the other very easily. Indeed, if you have sufficient storage capacity, two or more Windows virtual machines can be set up.  I have 7 and 10 virtual machines on my MacBook Pro. Installing Windows is a breeze, but transferring the existing machine configuration will be an unavoidable chore; I don't know of any shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded image for Virtual Box has the name `IE11 - Win7.ova`, and the image for VMware is named `IE11_-_Win7-disk1.vmdk` - this means that your image can only run in VMware.

Yes, you are right you can run a .vmdk file in Virtual Box, but then this image should have been made for Virtual Box.

Comment: So, did you check the link on my question? that is an Official link from MS dev site, where you choose, your current platform, then the app you use for the virtualization, what am I supposed to do then?

Comment: Yes, I did see the link - and Yes it may work, but if it doesn't, then you need to convert it to a Virtual Box usable image - or use the already available image for Virtual Box.